# How to check if user already like the post or not in simple like system?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a created simple like system with Laravel framework

Here's my table schema look like:

```
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('by_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My Eloquent relationship is simple:

```
Auth::user()->likes()->create(['post_id' => 'xxx']);
```

It's working as I want it to be

And In like page, I can show all posts that user xxx likes

```
@foreach ($user->likes as $post)
    ...
@endforeach
```

Pretty much simple

And now in home page, I want to show random posts

So I code this way:

```
$posts = Post::inRandomOrder()->get();

@foreach ($posts as post)
    ...
    
    // In each of these random post, check if user already like the post or not
    // If they do, show a button to delete the like
    // Else show button to like the post
@endforeach
```

In each of those random post, I want to know if current login user already like the post or not

So how to achieve this?

> Sorry for bad english

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid multiple queries, you could use an array of post ID's and check the existence of the random posts in that array:

```php
$userPostLikes = $user->likes->pluck('post_id');

$posts = Post::inRandomOrder()->get();

@foreach ($posts as post)

  @if(in_array($post->id, $userPostLikes)) 
     user likes post
  @else
     user doesn't likes post
  @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: Hello sir Repox, thank your for your answer, its working like I wanted, but the first time I tried it out, `$likedPost` return collection, so after reading few sites, I have to put `toArray()` so `in_array()` can work, and again, thank you sir Repox